# permanent redirection not working for everything

Tags: http, redirect

I am trying to permanently redirect one of my domain to another with a new extension, like example.com redirected to example.bizz.
I modified htacess and put this line :

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.bizz/
```

but as a result only http://example.com do redirect correctly to https://example.bizz ....it doesn't work for https://example.com --- Err_connection_reset
http://www.example.com  ---- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How can i have the redirect to apply on all adresses ?
Thanks for any help you can provide

here is the DNS configuration i got from my hosting

```
$TTL 3600
@   IN SOA dns200.anycast.me. tech.ovh.net. (2021032400 86400 3600 3600000 300)
                          IN NS     dns200.anycast.me.
                          IN NS     ns200.anycast.me.
                          IN MX     1 mx1.ovh.net.
                          IN MX     5 mx2.ovh.net.
                          IN MX     100 mxb.ovh.net.
                          IN A      2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                      600 IN TXT    "v=spf1 include:mx.ovh.com ~all"
                       60 IN TXT    "4|https://example.com/"
_autodiscover._tcp        IN SRV    0 0 443 mailconfig.ovh.net.
_imaps._tcp               IN SRV    0 0 993 ssl0.ovh.net.
_submission._tcp          IN SRV    0 0 465 ssl0.ovh.net.
autoconfig                IN CNAME  mailconfig.ovh.net.
autodiscover              IN CNAME  mailconfig.ovh.net.
ftp                       IN CNAME  ftp.cluster003.ovh.net.
imap                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
mail                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
pop3                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
smtp                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
```

Comment: Are the DNS records correctly configured for your domain?

Comment: @AmitVerma i updated the post with the DNS configuration (anonymized)

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache? Try a different browser to test the URL.

Comment: yes...i did both, and also tried private navigation from chrome...can't see where is the mistake. is there something to add in the directive ? some wildcard to say to include all "versions" of domain ? (http / https / www)

Comment: I think You need to add a DNS record for your `www` subdomain.  Try creating a new DNS CNAME  record  `WWW   points to  example.com TTL- automatic`

Comment: @AmitVerma thanks for the suggestion but do you think it can solves the issue i got with https://example.com not redirecting ? cause actually redirection works only for http://example.com which go to https://example.bizz